# References for Regularity Theory for p-Poisson Equation (Non Linear Elliptic Operators)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations

There is fairly good amount of literature available for the Regularity Theory for Linear Elliptic Operators. 
For my current requirement, I seek a good reference for the corresponding results in case of p-Laplacian.

Any Suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0):

The best regularity is $C^{1,\alpha}$ for $p\neq 2$. This is proved in many places; for instance:

Lawrence C Evans, A new proof of local C1,α regularity for solutions of certain degenerate elliptic p.d.e., In Journal of Differential Equations, Volume 45, Issue 3, 1982, Pages 356-373.

Near points where $\nabla u \neq 0$, the equation is uniformly elliptic and elliptic regularity can be used to show that the solution is smooth.

There is a nice set of notes by Peter Lindqvist on the pLaplacian which summarizes the known regularity results:

https://folk.ntnu.no/lqvist/p-laplace.pdf